# Write a function that randomly picks a string from array in C++

Tags: c++, random, constructor

I am in a C++ beginning programming class and we are currently studying classes and constructors. I have been stuck on an assignment where we must write a function to randomly pick a color from our color array. Below is what I have so far. I think I am close but I am getting a compiler error and not sure how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class ColorClass {
    public:
        ColorClass() {
            setColors();
        }
        void setColors() {
            colors[7] = {"Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, Indigo"};
        }
        const std::string getColors() {
            return colors[7];
        }
        std::string randomizeColor() {
            cout << "the colors are: " << colors;
            string word = colors[rand() % 7];
            cout << "word is :" << word;
            return word;
        }
    private:
        std::string colors[7];
};

int main() {
    srand (time(NULL)); //initialize the random seed
    ColorClass colorClass;
    colorClass.setColors();
    cout << colorClass.getColors() << endl;
    cout << colorClass.randomizeColor() << endl;

    colorClass.requirement();

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error is something like

> no viable conversion from std::__1::basic_string...std::_1::allocator

(too long to type out, but hoping someone understands this on first glance).

Comment: You confound array with element from its array.

Comment: Seed (`srand (time(NULL));`) only once (in `main`) BTW.

Comment: Out of bounds access with `colors[7] = x;`.

Comment: Your constructor should be `/*explicit*/ ColorClass(const std::vector<string>& colors)`.

Comment: `return colors[7];` is also a bug.

Comment: Why are you passing a string to `randomizeColor()`?

Comment: You seem to have a great difficulty with the difference between a single string and an array of strings. These are 2 very different things. You can't mix and match the two.

Comment: @drescherjm You are right. I got confused because of some hints on the assignment. Now that I changed all the string types to array of strings, I am still getting the same compiler error. I just started learning C++ last week, btw....

Comment: I hope you got rid if the parameter in `randomizeColor()`. Use the member variable colors instead of trying to pass the colors. And make sure you return a std::string. So the signature of randomizeColor is `std::string randomizeColor()`.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. That is really helpful. Now in that function I have `string word = colors[rand() % 7];` But when I print out the word, it is empty.

Comment: You probably have implemented your constructor wrongly. Use a debugger and inspect colors. If you still have `"Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, Indigo"` you need to fix that. There is no way `c++` will transform that into an array of strings.

Comment: @drescherjm I have updated my code to show what it currently looks like

Comment: `colors[7] = {"Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, Indigo"};` is still  wrong. This attempts to set colors[7] (the string 1 past the end of the array) to "Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, Indigo" colors[0] .. colors[6] will remain empty strings.

Comment: @drescherjm should it be like this `string colors[7] = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Indigo"};` thanks for your help btw...

Comment: Putting the string in front makes it a local variable. I think you want to create the string array in main() and pass the array along with its size to your constructor. In the constructor you need to copy the array using a loop. When you learn `c++` there will be easier ways to do what you want. However I bet you don't know what std::array<> or std::vector<> are.

Answer (score 1):

`x[rand() % 7]` is of type char and you're trying to initialize a string with it.

If that's really what you want to do, then use this constructor to build a string from a single character:

```
string(1, x[rand() % 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code could look like:

```
class ColorClass
{
    public:
        const std::vector<std::string>& getColors()  const { return colors; }

        void print() const {
            std::cout << "the colors are:\n";
            for (const auto& color : colors) {
                std::cout << color << std::endl;   
            }

        }

        const std::string& randomizeColor() const {
            return colors[rand() % colors.size()];
        }
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> colors = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Indigo"};
};

int main() {
    srand (time(NULL)); //initialize the random seed

    ColorClass colorClass;
    colorClass.print();
    std::cout << "random pick:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << colorClass.randomizeColor() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mgCnrO)

Ideally, `srand`/`rand` should be replaced with new facilities from `<random>`.

Answer (score 0):

Im in newbie too but what i see if you can't divide a string % 7

```
string word = x[rand() % 7];
```

try to replace string

maybe im wrong :P